# MacOS creates a new mount on AFP path calls

Tags: mac-osx, mount, firefox, afp

following scenario:

In my webapp, my customers are using Firefox as target browser. They have the need to open `afp://` folders via Javascript. To make a long story short, this really works. You need to setup Firefox with `about:config` and set the value `network.protocol-handler.external.afp` to true.

What happens then, the operating system (OSX) takes care of that path and it correctly opens a `Finder` window.

**The problem**:

OSX does create a new mount every time. It cannot distinct between `afp://host/path/111` and `afp://host/path/222` for instance.
Furthermore, even if the afp path is 100% identical a new mount is created. It looks like this is the default behavior from OSX regardless of Firefox.

So, is there any chance I can tell OSX not to create a new mount for some sub directorys which should get access over `afp://` ?

---

update:

It looks like, there are OSX applications which can change the default behavior for network protocols. So you can change "somewhere" which application OSX should call for a protocol. If that is true, wouldn't it be possible to create a script which just opens the local path without a `afp://` prefix ?

The question here is, where is that configuration (?) to tell OSX which application to use for specific protocol. Any help welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Ahh I had a totally different response worked out and then figured out the reason why this is a problem.

The reason this is a problem is because, once an AFP share is mounted, it is essentially a local "Volume". Thus, listing it as a mounted Volume locally on said machine. So, using another "AFP://" link of any sort would open a NEW AFP connection to the server itself.

Comment: Yes, but what is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) to set the application to use for a given URL scheme (afp in your case). Note that the application should probably declare its ability to handle the afp scheme in its Info.plist file, under the key CFBundleURLTypes.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what @Hacha said; you´re indeed creating a new mountpoint with every `afp://` call and make it a `/Volume/mountpoint`. Instead of calling afp everytime, I´d suggest opening the top folder *once* via `afp://server/mountpoint` and then use a file url `file:///Volumes/mountpoint` instead.